# Add logged in firebase user details such as displayName, phoneNumber etc using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

I need to add custom details such as name, mobile number etc to the already existing firebase logged in user using angular

i tried something like this

```
 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  user.updateProfile({
    displayName: "Jane Q. User",
    photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
  }).then(function() {
    // Update successful.
  }, function(error) {
    // An error happened.
  });
```

But the above code is not working

Comment: Can you try to log the `user` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in service.ts

```
getCurrentUser(name,picURL){
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      var user = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if (user) {
          console.log(user);
          resolve(user);

        user.updateProfile( {
            displayName: name ,
            photoURL :picURl,
          })
        } else {
          reject('No user logged in');
        }
      })
    })
  }
```